# Finding optimal subsequence in a path

Tags: algorithm, geometry, dynamic-programming, graph-theory

A path for the context of this question is a collection of points with integer coordinates v<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>, v<sub>3</sub> ... v<sub>n</sub> such that v<sub>1</sub> is connected to v<sub>2</sub>, v<sub>2</sub> is connected to v<sub>3</sub> and so on. The path is non-cyclic and does not have any branches.
(By v and u are connected it means that the absolute difference between their either x or y coordinate is equal to 1)

We say there is a possible segment between v<sub>i</sub> and v<sub>j</sub> if they follow some criteria which is irrelevant to this question.

c<sub>i</sub> represents the farthest point on the path in the forward direction such that there is a possible segment between v<sub>i</sub> and c<sub>i</sub>. (c<sub>i</sub> lies ahead of v<sub>i</sub>)
d<sub>i</sub> represents the farthest point on the path in the backward direction such that there is a possible segment between v<sub>i</sub> and d<sub>i</sub>. (v<sub>i</sub> lies ahead of d<sub>i</sub>)
Note: If there is a possible segment between u and v then there is a possible segment between any of its sub segments.

 The values of c<sub>i</sub> and d<sub>i</sub> are already calculated for each i.

For each pair v<sub>i</sub> and v<sub>j</sub> there is a penalty associated which also has been calculated for each i and j.

A sequence in a path is a collection of points of the path u<sub>1</sub>, u<sub>2</sub>, u<sub>3</sub> ... u<sub>m</sub> (not necessarily connected) such that u<sub>1</sub> = v<sub>1</sub>, u<sub>m</sub> = v<sub>n</sub> and there is a possible segment between each u<sub>i</sub> and u<sub>i+1</sub>.

Number of segments in such a cycle is (m-1).

The problem is to find the most optimal sequence which is a sequence having minimum number of segments possible and of all the such possible sequences have minimum sum of penalties of consecutive points in that sequence.

This problem is solved in a program called potrace which I am trying to implement but that implementation uses cyclic paths while my program uses non-cyclic.
I also cannot understand how the potrace implementation below works in the first place.

In the implementation below `clip0[i]` represents c<sub>i</sub> and `clip1[i]` represents d<sub>i</sub>.

In potrace implementation cyclic means v<sub>1</sub> and v<sub>n</sub> are also connected in the path.

[Source](https://github.com/skyrpex/potrace/blob/master/src/trace.c) Line 575

 [Documentation](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/potrace.pdf) 2.2.4

```cpp
/* calculate seg0[j] = longest path from 0 with j segments */
i = 0;
for (j=0; i<n; j++) {
  seg0[j] = i;
  i = clip0[i];
}
seg0[j] = n;
m = j;
/* calculate seg1[j] = longest path to n with m-j segments */
i = n;
for (j=m; j>0; j--) {
  seg1[j] = i;
  i = clip1[i];
}
seg1[0] = 0;
/* now find the shortest path with m segments, based on penalty3 */
/* note: the outer 2 loops jointly have at most n iterations, thus
   the worst-case behavior here is quadratic. In practice, it is
   close to linear since the inner loop tends to be short. */
pen[0]=0;
for (j=1; j<=m; j++) {
  for (i=seg1[j]; i<=seg0[j]; i++) {
    best = -1;
    for (k=seg0[j-1]; k>=clip1[i]; k--) {
    thispen = penalty3(pp, k, i) + pen[k];
    if (best < 0 || thispen < best) {
      prev[i] = k;
      best = thispen;
    }
    }
    pen[i] = best;
  }
}

pp->m = m;
SAFE_CALLOC(pp->po, m, int); // output
/* read off shortest path */
for (i=n, j=m-1; i>0; j--) {
  i = prev[i];
  pp->po[j] = i;
}
```

A sample input can be [this](https://pastebin.com/HS1QzSMB).

EDIT 1:
So when I implemented the same code for my case the last loop was breaking the code, the index value j was either becoming negative (without self looping) or `i = prev[i]` was self looping.

The penalty values are positive.

EDIT 2:
I coded vaguely the Dijkstra's algorithm and it seems to be working.

 I am providing my relevant bit of code below.

```cpp
using Weight = std::pair<int, float>;
std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, Weight>>> graph;
graph.resize(n);
/*This takes O(n^2).*/
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j = clip1[i]; j <= clip0[i]; ++j) {
        float pen = calculatePenalty(index, i, j);
        graph[i].emplace_back(j, Weight(1, pen));
        graph[j].emplace_back(i, Weight(1, pen));
    }
}

std::vector<bool> vis(n, false);
std::vector<Weight> dist(n, {10e5 + 1, 0.0f});
std::vector<int> prev(n, 0);
dist[0] = {0, 0.0f};

std::multiset<std::pair<Weight, int>> set;
set.insert({{0, 0.0f}, 0});

while (!set.empty()) {
    auto p = *set.begin();
    set.erase(set.begin());

    int x = p.second;
    Weight w0 = p.first;

    if (vis[x]) continue;
    vis[x] = true;

    for (auto v : graph[x]) {
        int e = v.first;
        Weight w = v.second;
        Weight w_ = {dist[x].first + w.first, dist[x].second + w.second};

        if (w_ < dist[e]) {
            prev[e] = x;
            dist[e] = w_;
            set.insert({dist[e], e});
        }

    }
}

for (int i = n - 1; i > 0;) {
    seq.push_back(i);
    i = prev[i];
}
seq.push_back(0);
```

If there are any errors in the above code then please correct it.

 I think a number of improvements can be made in the above code.

 The initialization of the graph itself has O(n^2) complexity. There should be an alternative way to do this part or the whole part.

Its also not so compact as the potrace counter part. A more compact implementation with better time complexity seems possible. If someone could provide some pseudocode in that direction than that would be appreciated.

 Also in the potrace implementation it seems that the number of segments is precisely `m`. But when I compute `m` in my case and compare it with `seg.size() - 1`, it is not equal. (It is both greater and less in different cases but not by a large margin.)

Comment: "This problem is solved in an algorithm called portrace"  Never heard of it.  Do you have a link to some docs for this?

Comment: The algorithm is a program. https://github.com/skyrpex/potrace/blob/master/src/trace.c The code I've mentioned that is relevant starts from the line 575

Comment: You should correct the spelling and add the link to your question.

Comment: Potrace is a program, I'll clarify it in the question.

Comment: "I also cannot understand how the potrace implementation below works"  ( Notice the spelling? )  Suggest you ask the potrace maintainer.

Comment: I emailed the creator of potrace. What shall I do to improve the question?

Comment: Fix the spelling.  Explain what you are trying to achieve,  Provide some sample input with the resulting output and an explanation of what is exactly wrong.  Provide a minimal executable program that simply as possible shows the problem.  All the usual things. Google 'stackoverflow how to ask a question'

Comment: I cannot seem to find which spelling your are talking about. A sample input has been provided but a minimum executable program is not possible as that is what I need to find, an algorithm that finds an optimal subsequence. The code that I have provided is what I am using as reference, what that code does is what I am trying to understand and achieve.

Comment: Third word in question title is misspelled. Sometimes you write 'portrace' sometimes 'potrace'.  ( If you cannot proof read your own writing, then how do you expect to write correct code? )

Comment: I fixed the title. Its potrace everywhere, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're describing is the (single-source single-destination) [shortest-path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem), where an edge's weight is `(1, penalty)` (and weights are summed elementwise and ordered lexically, so minimizing number of edges is first priority and minimizing total penalty is second priority).  You can solve this problem in near-linear time with [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) if all your penalties are positive (or zero).  In this case, you can prove that the shortest path will never repeat any vertices.

potrace's implementation looks roughly like [Bellman-Ford's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) (in dynamic programming interpretation), which is a good approach if you have a mixture of positive and negative penalties (but unnecessarily slow if you have only positive penalties).  In this case, the shortest path *might* repeat vertices, but when that happens, the path will actually repeat some vertices (a negative-weight cycle) infinitely many times, which is probably not what you want.